# requirejs client/server module with jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, requirejs

My requirejs module has a methods for server and client side. Also module has jQuery dependency. How i can drown out the jquery loading on server

For example

app structure:

```
| -public
| | -ext
| | | -requirejs
| | | | -require.js
| | -lib
| | | -a.js
| | -main.js
| -index.js
```

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: './lib/',
    paths : {
      "jquery" : "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min"
   }
});
```

a.js

```
define("a", ["jquery"], function($){
   return {
      serverMethod : function(){
         console.log("asdasdasd");
      },
      clientMethod : function(){
         //work with jquery
      }
   }
});
```

and nodejs code (index.js)

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: "./public/lib/"
});

requirejs(["a"], function(a){  //Error: Tried loading "jquery" at ./public/lib/jquery.js then tried node's require("jquery")
   a.serverMethod();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Foreword

You might take a closer look what the dependency is used for and try to refactor your code to get rid of dependencies like jQuery in base models of the server side model (or the server sie model directly).

Even in a very huge project consisting of 10+ models there were only two models directly using jQuery `ajax` (and if reuing them on the server side would be an issue, this can easily be refactored).

## Answer

I would define a `jquery` named module in NodeJs and return a stub instead.

Note: I'm using [`shim`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) to define the modules. Using AMD-aware forks as direct modules (which some people discourage to use) may not work.

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
   baseUrl: "./public/lib/"
});

requirejs.define("jquery", [], function(){
   return {jQueryStub: true};
});

requirejs(["a"], function(a){  //Error: Tried loading "jquery" at ./public/lib/jquery.js then tried node's require("jquery")
   a.serverMethod();
});
```

Besides, [regarding to the RequireJs documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html), you probably want to tell RequireJs that it runs inside NodeJS:

```
requirejs.config({
   nodeRequire: require,
   baseUrl: "./public/lib/"
});
```

As far as I can see (re)using only the models on the server side does not require jQuery. (Note: I've only built a small project that reuses models and parts of the views in a Grunt process.)